# ServiceStack Ormlite Reference Attribute For Same Type

Tags: c#, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

In ServiceStack OrmLite, I have a table defined as follows:

```cs
public class Foo {
    [PrimaryKey]
    [AutoIncrement]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Bar))]
    public long BarAId { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Bar))]
    public long BarBId { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public Bar BarA { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public Bar BarB { get; set; }
}
```

Where obviously Bar is another table, and BarA and BarB refer to two different entries in the parent table. When I attempt to resolve BarA and BarB, they're the same. Is there any way to do auto referencing with two parent objects of the same type, or am I SOL and just need to do the join manually?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for multiple Self References was [added in this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/771d1c421665853be10aae28c8304865fca73913).

In order to be able to the match the fields with the correct reference, the FK Reference Id has to take the format `{ReferenceProperty}Id` which you've also done in your example:

```
public class Foo 
{
    ...
    [References(typeof(Bar))]
    public long BarAId { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public Bar BarA { get; set; }

    [References(typeof(Bar))]
    public long BarBId { get; set; }

    [Reference]
    public Bar BarB { get; set; }
}
```

This feature is available from **v4.0.33+** that's [now available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).

Comment: For posterity's sake, I also created issue 168 for the problem ( https://github.com/ServiceStack/Issues/issues/168 ). Thanks mythz for the quick response and turnaround! Great product!